# How to debug a non-exported function?

Tags: r, debugging

There's a [definitive guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function/19226817#19226817) for how to view the source code for a function, but how do you debug a function that's not exported from a package, without manually stepping through the source code that you've found?

```
library(plm)
> predict.plm
Error: object 'predict.plm' not found
> plm:::predict.plm
function (object, newdata = NULL, ...) 
{
    tt <- terms(object)
    if (is.null(newdata)) {
        result <- fitted(object, ...)
    }
    else {
        Terms <- delete.response(tt)
        m <- model.frame(Terms, newdata)
        X <- model.matrix(Terms, m)
        beta <- coef(object)
        result <- as.numeric(crossprod(beta, t(X)))
    }
    result
}
<environment: namespace:plm>
> debugonce("predict.plm")
Error in debugonce("predict.plm") : could not find function "predict.plm"
> debugonce("plm:::predict.plm")
Error in debugonce("plm:::predict.plm") : 
  could not find function "plm:::predict.plm"
```

Comment: (+1) This is a great (and useful) question, as I am currently learning to write R extensions.  So thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not at all obvious, but giving the argument as a symbol rather than as a quoted string seems to work fine, i.e.

```
debugonce(plm:::predict.plm)
```

rather than

```
debugonce("plm:::predict.plm")
```

Comment: I'm pretty shocked that `fun="whatever"` actually works in some cases, since `?debug` says `fun` is supposed to be a function. I never would have thought to try setting `fun` to a string.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich this has baffled me when I call `do.call`. Passing function is a string feels very unRlike.

Comment: Counter-argument: Passing a function implies that its contents are copied (pass by value), rather than that debug is told where to look and intervene whenever the original function is called.  Clearly unquoted is the right way here, but I'm not sure it's more intuitive or R-like.

Comment: For reference, note the triple colon ```:::```, as compared to double, which will not allow you to access the internal function.

Answer (score 8):

One trick I've used is to assign first to a local object:

```
predict.plm <- plm:::predict.plm
```

after which you can do `fix()`, `debug()`, ... the local copy.

Comment: Depending on the situation (i.e. if the functions are being called from within package functions), I can imagine that one would run into trouble because functions within the package would still see the version in the NAMESPACE first rather than the local copy ...

Comment: I wound up solving it doing something similar (copy/pasting into a local object).

Comment: Yes, I've done it that way too. And often I give it a local prefix, eg `mypredict` to overcome the name clash @BenBolker alluded to.

Answer (score 0):

I do this trick: suppose you have to debug the codeline

```
rmarkdown::render("myDocument.Rmd")
```

Then you can add avobe y below the codeline

```
f <- function () {
  rmarkdown::render("myDocument.Rmd") 
}
```

Next

```
debug(f)
f ()
```